# Auto Reloading does not work in 7.9

Tags: intershop

In my local development installation of Intershop Commerce Management 7.9 the property "intershop.template.checkSource" is set to "true", but if I modify a template in Intershop Studio, the change does not become visible.

A look in SMC under "Monitoring > Cartridges > Loaded Cartridges" shows that my cartridges are still loaded from the server folder "share/system/cartridges".

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run a

**gradlew enableHotCodeReloading**

and then deploy the server again.

See
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/280E17

The enableHotCodeReloading task ensures that your locally built cartridges are monitored by the development server for changes. It does so by changing .gradle\gradle.properties